# Deserialization does not work for dynamic properties if using Json.NET attributes

Tags: c#, wcf, json.net

## The Problem

Hi all,

I'm trying to deserialize Json-strings with known (static) and unknown (dynamic) properties. For this I'm using Json.NET and `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`.
In my first attempt, I was using Json.NET-specific [Serialization Attributes](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to configure the (de-)serializer. However the dynamic properties in the Json-string are not deserialized in that case. But when I switch to native .NET attributes (`[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`), the dynamic properties are deserialized and I can access them in the created dynamic object.

Is this behavior intended? Am I missing any configuration with the Json.NET attributes to get the same deserialization behavior?

Any clarification would be highly appreciated!

## The Details

Here I'm providing the details of my implementation (using Json.NET attributes). I'm using **.NET 4.5 and Json.NET 6.0.2**

Because I have multiple message types with static and dynamic properties, I introduced a base class, which implements the dynamic handling property:

```
[JsonObject]
internal abstract class DynamicMessage : DynamicObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public Dictionary<string, object> dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {...}
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {...}
}
```

The concrete subclass is looks like this:

```
[JsonObject]
internal class ItemMessage : DynamicMessage
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute(PropertyName = "id")]
    internal long Id;
    [JsonPropertyAttribute(PropertyName = "parent_item");
    internal long ParentItemId;
    ...
}
```

And I tried the deserialize the following string like this:

```
jsonString = @{'id':1,
'parent_item':5,
'my_dynamic_property_1' : 1337,
'my_dynamic_property_2' : 'my_dynamic_property_2'}

JsonSerializer serializer  = new JsonSerializer();
dynamic itemMessage = serializer.Deserialize<ItemMessage>(new JsonTextReader(jsonString));
```

As I pointed out in the beginning, if I'm using the attributes `[JsonObject]` and `[JsonProperty]` all static properties are correctly deserialized and bound to the POCO properties, **but I'm lacking the dynamic properties `my_dynamic_property_1` and `my_dynamic_property_2`.**

When I change to `[DataContract]` (for `[JsonObject]`) and `[DataMember]` (for `[JsonProperty]`) also the dynamic properties in the Json will be deserialized and I can call

```
itemMessage.my_dynamic_property_1; //=1337
itemMessage.my_dynamic_property_2; //="my_dynamic_property_2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[JsonProperty]` always binds a single property in the JSON to a single member in a class.  You cannot use it to bind multiple JSON properties to a single dictionary.  It doesn't work that way.

However, Json.Net does have a `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute that works the way you want.  Try this instead:

```
[JsonObject]
internal abstract class DynamicMessage : DynamicObject
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> dynamicProperties = 
                                             new Dictionary<string, object>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brian! You made my day! That was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but you can always deserialize into a dictionary.

```
var jsonString = @"{'id':1,
'parent_item':5,
'parent_details':{'name': 'parent_name', 'description': 'parent description'},
'array':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
'my_dynamic_property_1' : 1337,
'my_dynamic_property_2' : 'my_dynamic_property_2'}";

Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
```

I added a nested object so you can see that it still deserializes into another dictionary with dynamic values to keep everything typed correctly, I also added an array of integers for the same purposes.

You can access your dynamic properties like this:

```
values[my_dynamic_property_1];
```

Although I would recommend casting the known types like so:

```
var prop1 = (int)values["my_dynamic_property_1"];
```

As for the nested object, you can access the members directly like so:

```
var parentDescription = values["parent_details"]["name"];
```

Comment: Hi Smeegs, thanks you very much! But indeed that's not the answer I'm looking for. I hope to get any clarification why the deserialization of dynamic Json properties is only working if I use native .NET serialization attributes.